# How to make a tabbar click show one of two viewControllers, depending if user is logged in?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, interface-builder

Users can use the app without having to be logged in. However, if they go to the "profile" tab, of the tabbar, then:

1) if they are logged in, it shows them their profile.

2) if they are not logged in, it shows them a login page.

I can't figure out the best way to have this happen, because, I of course want to maintain the tabbar for both 1 and 2. If I segue with push or push detail from 1->2 or 2->1, the tabbar disappears.

Comment: why not just presenting a login formsheet (UIModalPresentationFormSheet) when the user is not login?

Comment: Give your minimal code and the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass and write the UITabBarController. From that class you can set your tab bar view controllers. When setting the view controllers you can check whether the user is loggedIn or not. If user is loggedIn then you can set the view controller as Profile view else you can set the view as login view.

If user is going to login from that screen then you have to update the login view controller tab with profile view controller